# Change the size of only a part/subset of a single equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, lyx, fontsize

For example, I'd like to do:

```
$Q^{r<1}$
```

but with the `r<1` having a much smaller font size than the `Q`. Of course `r<1` will naturally have a smaller size since it is a superscript, but I want to make it even smaller, without changing the size of `Q`.

I prefer a solution in LyX, but a TeX solution will do.

Comment: Hmm, when I compile, the font size of `r<1` is smaller than `Q`. What do you get?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks kan and Torbjorn. kan you are right (I have edited my question to reflect this).

Comment: @Jubobs -- the cited question asks specifically how to make parts of an equation larger.  this one is about making something smaller.  `$Q^{\scriptscriptstyle r<1}$` should do that, and i'm not sure a new user would know that.  {i also don't think that it's a good idea.}

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry for not replying earlier. Doesn't Stefan's answer address both cases (larger and smaller)?

Comment: @Jubobs, @barbara beeton: I do not necessarily think that this is a duplicate question. The referenced duplicate explains how to make math text smaller in a systematic way, but it is possible that this question desires an "exception to the rule" kind of answer, given that the superscripted material is not a typical exponent. He may want to leave exponentiation the defaulte size, but for this kind of superscript change the size. Something like a `$Q^{\scaleto{r<1}{.5ex}}$` from the `scalerel` package could achieve this.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- yes, i read this as a request for an "exceptional" case, not global.  the op needs to clarify.

Comment: @user1271772 -- do you mean that you want to reduce the size of *all* superscripts and subscripts, or only for this one cited case?

Comment: @Jubobs, Marco, Herbert, Thorsten, Xavier: I'd very much appreciate if you can remove the '[duplicate]' which has been added to my title. That article that you linked this to is focused on keeping the font size of everything within an equation the same (overriding the default setting that makes certain parts smaller as the equation gets more complex). That article came up in my google search before I posted here, but it is orthogonal to my question, and other people that search "change size of ONLY PART of an equation" should be directed here, not there. Respectfully yours, OP

Comment: That article you linked this to would be less ambiguous if it was called "Overriding the default setting which shrinks parts of an equation as the equation gets more complex".

Comment: @barbarabeeton's answer `$Q^{\scriptscriptstyle r<1}$` worked =) However I'd like to make the superscript even smaller. I tried @Steven's solution `$Q^{\scaleto{r<1}{.5ex}}$` but it seems like a nightmare in LyX because it seems I'd have to make the *entire* equation in ERT (Evil Red Text) in order for it to work. I'm still looking for a solution that makes the superscript smaller than `\scriptscriptstyle` in LyX

Comment: In Lyx you can define a math macro that contains TeX code but displays something else. So it should definitely allow you to do what you want and still input the formula in LyX.

Comment: Thank you @user21820 can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: Okay sure. I thought this was an old question so I thought you may have figured it out already. I'll give an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really need to go smaller than scriptscriptsyle, you could use scalebox (but it's getting very small to read)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


$Q^{r<1}$

$Q^{\scriptscriptstyle r<2}$

$Q^{\scalebox{.2}{$r<4$}}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method**

1. Insert math macro (from the menu or the "\foo:=" button on the toolbar)

   a. For Name type say "qp" .

   b. For TeX type exactly "\mathbb Q ^\scalebox{.5 {#1" The result should look like "Q<sup>\scalebox{.5}{#1}</sup>". This will be output in the LaTeX.

   c. For Lyx type say "\mathbb Q ^#1 _\circ". The result should look like "Q<sub>°</sub><sup>#1</sup>". This will be displayed in Lyx.
2. Go to Document Settings LaTeX Preamble and add "\usepackage{graphicx}".
3. Write your document after the macro definition and use "\qp" wherever you want this tiny power of Q.

**Notes**

You are of course free to choose a different macro name as well as a different LyX part. I chose to use "_\circ" to clearly distinguish it from the usual "\mathbb{Q}".